# Replacing GET variables names with slash

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, get

I have URL like http://www.blah.eu/cats/black_cats?age=over-10-years&sex=male and I would like to parse it into http://www.blah.eu/cats/black_cats/over-10-years/male without losing $_GET information (for PHP to be able to parse it, basically.
My current .htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Is it in any way possible? Unfortunately I am not yet familiar with Apache servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this line just below RewriteRule line where you're adding www.

```
RewriteRule ^(cats)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2?age=$3&sex=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```